# Subtable Reference Numbers Start at Zero

Tags: tables, numbering, subfloats

I have a latex document with a table that contains two subtables.  When I reference the entire table it the numbering starts at 1, but when I reference one of the individual subtables the numbering starts with 0. Here is an example of my setup:

```
% In my preamble
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}

% In my document section
\section{Section}
\subsection{Sub Section}

% My Table
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \subtable[Sub Table 1]
  {
    \label{tbl:sub-table-1}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ l c }
      \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} \\
      1 & 2 \\
      2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \subtable[Sub Table 2]
  {
    \label{tbl:sub-table-2}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ l c }
      \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} \\
      1 & 2 \\
      2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \caption{Sub Tables}
  \label{tbl:table-1}
\end{table}

This it my sub table \ref{tbl:sub-table-1}. % Comes out 0(a) instead of 1(a)
This is my table \ref{tbl:table-1}. % Comes out to 1 as you expect
```

Comment: Table captions are normally on top of the table, not below like figure captions. Move the `\caption` before the `\subtable`s and look if it changes the numbering.

Comment: ...otherwise take a look at the subfigure documentation, there is an option for sub-captions below the tables. (Something like "subfigcap", can't remember the name.) Once you have found and used it, the numbering should be correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`subfigure` is an obsolete package and shouldn't be used anymore. You can use the `subcaption` package instead:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[subtable]{font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Sub Section}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \subcaption{Subtable 1}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c }
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} \\
    1 & 2 \\
    2 & 3 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tbl:sub-table-1}
  \end{subtable}  
  \begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \subcaption{Subtable 2}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c }
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} \\
    1 & 2 \\
    2 & 3 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tbl:sub-table-2}
  \end{subtable}  
  \caption{Sub Tables}
  \label{tbl:table-1}
\end{table}

This it my subtable~\ref{tbl:sub-table-1}.
This is my table~\ref{tbl:table-1}.

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I added the `\captionsetup` command (to change the font size for the subtable captions).

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about this package.  The interface is much cleaner than the `subfigure` package.

Comment: Ok I will give this a try I had not hear of this package either.  When/if it works I will accept your answer.

Comment: Ok that worked, but I couldn't get the two to work together so I had to go change a lot of other subfigure's in my document.  Does anyone happen to know how to center the caption text?

Comment: @Joe: the caption is centered by default if it fits in one line. Are you getting something different?

Comment: Yeah, it flowed over onto two lines but I was able to add a \centering to the caption and that got it centered.